# Assign IPs to Docker containers hosted on VM

Tags: docker, networking, virtualization

I have server connected to router by eth0 interface. On this server I have installed kimchi (GUI for kvm). Using this GUI I am able to create macvtap network interface attached to eth0 and assign LAN IPs to virtual machines. The gate is 192.168.0.1, the host is 192.168.0.80.

On this server I'm creating docker1 VM with ip 192.168.0.100. On this VM there is a docker installed.

I'm also following this how-to - https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization_Host_Configuration_and_Guest_Installation_Guide/App_Macvtap.html to connect host to guests (creating isolated network).

I want each container to have separate ip (192.168.0.101, 192.168.0.102, ...). I have tried different approaches and still am not able to. For example I tried to create another macvtap network for docker and use it, like this (ens3 is a network interface connected by macvtap to eth0 on host):

```
docker network create -d macvlan --subnet=192.168.0.0/24 --gateway=192.168.0.1  -o parent=ens3 pub_net
```

and then:

```
docker run --name name --restart always -d --network=pub_net --ip=192.168.0.102 -h this_container_host docker/docker
```

but it isn't working.

Comment: When you say not working can you explain what is not working?

Comment: Sure, I cannot see the hostname in 'connected_devices' on router interface, cannot ping the ip from laptop connected to the same lan network and f.e. if it's the plex container I cannot access the web interface

Comment: But I'm not very familiar with macvlan interfaces should it be working? container--(macvlan)-->ens3--(macvlan)-->eth0--(cable)-->router

Comment: You created a network named `macvlan` but the container is not a part of it, container belongs to network named `pub_net`

Comment: Hi Ayushya, I believe it is not true. In the command to create the network, i use "-d macvlan", where  "-d, --driver string - Driver to manage the Network (default "bridge")" and the name of the network is located in the end of the command. If i'm wrong can you say something more?